# Center absolute div under its parent using percentages not absolute values

Tags: html, css

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624676/positioning-an-absolute-element-in-the-center-of-its-relative-parent-element), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624159/centering-a-percent-based-div), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50717902/center-absolute-div-in-overflow-parent-css) question were similar but did not help.

The goal is to center an element under its parent using percentages, not absolute values. This way, position values do not need to change if sizes change.

The `hover` element below is centered under `outer`, but positioning requires absolute values that depend on the sizes of `hover` and `outer`. If either change, the position values must change.

Can centering underneath a parent be achieved with percentages?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dadjpg

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="hover"></div>
</div>

#outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

#hover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 75px;
  bottom: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `top:100%; left:0px; right:0px; margin:0px auto;`

```css
#outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

#hover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  top:100%;
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="hover"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `top:100%` to move the element to the bottom then simply combine `left:50%` with `translateX(-50%)` to center:

```css
#outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

#hover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  top:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="hover"></div>
</div>
```

Same logic considering `bottom:0`

```css
#outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

#hover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="hover"></div>
</div>
```

Another idea is to consider flexbox to center inside the element then translate to make the element outside:

```css
#outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
}

#hover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  margin:auto auto 0;
  transform:translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="hover"></div>
</div>
```